# Computer Graphics Question

Tags: mathematical-physics

I'm learning computer graphics, but there are still some problem i really confuse and have nothing to do, maybe i'm still a beginner or maybe it hard, but, i really willing to learn these things, please help, problem is:

**The winding number of a parametric curve γ about a point z0
of the complex plane is defined as:
$n(z_0,\gamma)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-z_0}$
Show that by parameterizing each edge of the polygon with vertices P1, . . . , Pn
with an interval of length 1, and treating the point with coordinates (x, y) as the
complex number x+iy, we can reduce this integral definition to the simplified one
we gave for polygons.**

thanks a lot, i very very grateful for your help!
i edited my question after using latex, thank for your advice

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Also, please post only one question at a time. That way, we can more easily focus on the question.

Comment: thanks you guys a lot, i"ll edit my first post